# Icomoon Custom font multiple colors

Tags: html, css

I am using Icomoon to create custom font icons, i have a situation where to icons need to be in the same span such as:

```
<span class="glyph2" aria-hidden="false" data-icon="&#xe000; &#xe001;"></span>
```

But they both need to be different colors. Is it possible at all to do this?

And here's the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yFeKM/) containing all the code, but i cant seem to get the custom fonts working in jsfiddle.

Any Help Greatly appreciated.

Comment: seeAlso : my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33371715/create-multicolor-icons-icomoon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible using only the data-icon attribute.

You could use IcoMoon's `icon-` classes instead and use the `before` CSS pseudo selector on one, and  the `after` selector on the second.

```
icon1:before {
    content: "A";
    color:red;
}

.icon2:after {
    color: blue;
    content: "B";
}
```

I have demonstrated this in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yFeKM/10/).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to demonstrate that in the fiddle, but it looks like it can work.

IcoMoon's are styling in an :before pseudo selector. Acordingly to css the first-letter pseudo-selector should work on the generated content, and so including the :before data.

So, including

```
.glyph2:first-letter {background-color: blue; color:white}
```

You should be able to give this appearance to the first icon (generated in 
a :before pseudo element with 2 custom chars).

It worked for me in local, but I couldn't get it to work in the fiddle.