# create multicolor icons. Icomoon

Tags: css, icons

It's been so hard to find any clear information about how to create icons with two colors (facebook -white and blue-, google- white and red.....). The customer wants to be able to change those two colors as he pleases. I have been looking around and I've found only http://www.programask.com/question_41701651_multicolored-icon-fonts# which seems quiet easy and clear for the client purpose (change the color when they want, but I haven't understood the procedure...).

I currently use icomoon, but I can't find how to add colors....

So I understood that I need an image editor, in case of facebook icon, I select the "f" and I save it in .svg and then the same with the background but "without the f", and I save it to svg too, but then.... how to I put them together to refer to just one icon?

I don't need to do it with icomoon though (but I need free software), but can someone explain me how to color icons through css?

Thank you

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or invites discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: what do you mean? It is a problem that I have with css!!!!! I am trying to color icons I've created through icomoon and I can only paint "the background", I've been trying to find on google how to create two colored svg icons and I can't find anything except the link I added, which I consider incomplete. Why is it not a topic for Stack Overflow?

Comment: thank you for the link. Although.... it is wrong. I can't use that way because my supervisor says it is wrong and a bad habit, I should use color paths no background images....

Comment: You didn't read far enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating multicolored icon fonts with icomoon is fairly easy but it combines them from multiple glyphs off course and seems to have no knowledge of a "default" color (the color which can be changed from the parent class) - so we need do define it as `inherit` in the CSS :

1) Create your SVGs with your favorite vector app like Inkscape or Adobe Illustrator.

Important : Icomoon (and anything else) will use one glyph for **each** colored path in the SVG, so make sure to join the pathes with the same color and don't use too many colors …

Illustrator makes it easy to join compound pathes : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbc3q9bfOH8 and to join objects: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/999/how-do-i-combine-two-objects-into-one-in-illustrator …

2) Make your icomoon font.

3) Determine your "default" color in the CSS - lets say it is `rgb(62, 55, 60);`:

In `[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {` add

```
/* default color */
color: rgb(62, 55, 60);
```

and remove every other line reading

```
color: rgb(62, 55, 60);
```

or to be explicit change it to

```
color: inherit;
```

That's it.

When I only use two colors (e.g. the darkgrey and orange) properly joined I would never get more than two children in the icon and I could change the darkgrey from the root node `<span class="icon-myIconName">` ...

Here is a working [codepen](http://codepen.io/sebilasse/pen/QKKLAj?editors=1100) with a 2-color font used with only one element where you can change the color …

Answer (score 6):

IcoMoon itself generates the CSS for stacking font glyphs. It doesn't use `:before` and `:after` (which is a good solution for 2 colors). Instead, it uses a more general approach with multiple `span`s. It works well for cases where you want to have more than one color. All you need to do is import a multicolor SVG to IcoMoon. It'll take care of the rest. Here's a demo of its output: https://codepen.io/Keyamoon/pen/vXxJgq

Answer (score 2):

The example in the link you provided is quite clear.
You create 2 SVGs. One for each of the 2 colors in your icon, and add them as two different characters to the font. (\e006 and \e0007 in the example)

Then you use both the `:before` selector and the `:after` selector to add the characters using different colors.
Each selector is using a different character and a different color.

The `letter-spacing: -1` causes the characters to overlap.

I took their jsfiddle example and fixed it to work with font awesome: http://jsfiddle.net/p44zf3se/

**Update**

I am not sure why my previous answer was not enough, but here is another example.
I can't upload it to jsfiddle because the font cannot be served from another site. So just take the html below + download the free IcoMoon font from: http://github.com/Keyamoon/IcoMoon-Free/raw/master/Font/IcoMoon-Free.ttf

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
@font-face  {
    font-family: 'IcoMoon-Free';
    src: url('IcoMoon-Free.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.facebook-icon {
    font-family: 'IcoMoon-Free';
}
.facebook-icon:after {
    content:"\ea8e";
    color:#F33;
    font-size:6em;
}
.facebook-icon:before {
    content:"\ea8c";
    color:#0C0;
    font-size:6em;
    letter-spacing:-0.5em;
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="facebook-icon"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes yes I have took its jsfiddle and I see how it works, but I don't understand the procedure on icomoon. So like the example I said. I want to do a facebook icon. I save in an svg the "f" and I save in another svg the background (with the gap for the "f"). But then, if I upload them on icomoon, they will appear as different icons, no? Or should I do that and then, once I have downloaded the generated files, I create the "facebook" icon?

Comment: You can't create multi-colored icons with Icomoon

Comment: The font is single color always. The facebook class is styled (using :before and :after) to contain 2 letters. each one in different color. You can upload your svgs or output woff file somewhere and I will update the example to work with it.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution 1: Not using a font**

You haven't said much about what you're actually doing. Building a website? A web-interface for a customer to edit an icon in the content management system *of* a website? I'm guessing.

It sounds like you're over-complicating things by thinking about fonts at all. They are usually monochromatic animals. Usually.

Why not just use an SVG? You can easily build or load one in Javascript, and edit it from Javascript; there are many online demos and I've provided another one here. Changing two colours would be pretty trivial, then.

Here is a quick way to build an SVG in a page, and even offer it for download as a standalone file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
  <title>Chess SVG Builder</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
 // Draw board
  var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0],
   sz = Math.min(svg.clientWidth, svg.clientHeight),
   sqr = sz / 11, smSqr = sqr / 2,
   xSmO = (svg.clientWidth - sz) / 2, ySmO = (svg.clientHeight - sz) / 2,
   xO = (svg.clientWidth - 8 * sqr) / 2, yO = (svg.clientHeight - 8 * sqr) / 2;
  svg.innerHTML = "";
  for (var x = 0; x < 22; x++) for (var y = x % 2; y < 3; y += 2)
    svg.innerHTML += '<rect x="' + (xSmO + smSqr * x) + '" y="' + (ySmO + smSqr * y) + '" width="' + smSqr + '" height="' + smSqr + '" style="fill:#eee;" />';
  for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) for (var y = x % 2; y < 19; y += 2)
    svg.innerHTML += '<rect x="' + (xSmO + smSqr * x) + '" y="' + (ySmO + smSqr * y) + '" width="' + smSqr + '" height="' + smSqr + '" style="fill:#eee;" />';
  for (var x = 19; x < 22; x++) for (var y = x % 2; y < 19; y += 2)
    svg.innerHTML += '<rect x="' + (xSmO + smSqr * x) + '" y="' + (ySmO + smSqr * y) + '" width="' + smSqr + '" height="' + smSqr + '" style="fill:#eee;" />';
  for (var x = 0; x < 22; x++) for (var y = 20 - x % 2; y < 22; y += 2)
    svg.innerHTML += '<rect x="' + (xSmO + smSqr * x) + '" y="' + (ySmO + smSqr * y) + '" width="' + smSqr + '" height="' + smSqr + '" style="fill:#eee;" />';
  for (var x = 0; x < 8; x++) for (var y = 1 - x % 2; y < 8; y += 2)
    svg.innerHTML += '<rect x="' + (xO + sqr * x) + '" y="' + (yO + sqr * y) + '" width="' + sqr + '" height="' + sqr + '" style="fill:#700;" />';
  svg.innerHTML += '<rect x="' + xO + '" y="' + yO + '" width="' + 8 * sqr + '" height="' + 8 * sqr + '" style="fill:none; stroke-width:1; stroke:#000;" />';
 // Print pieces
  svg.style.fontSize = sqr + "px";
  var numInstances = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 8],
          horz = [4, 3, 0, 7, 2, 5, 6, 1],
          pieceNum = 0;
  for (var code = 12; code < 24; code++)
   for (var lp = 0; lp < numInstances[code % 6]; lp++) {
    var pN = pieceNum % 16;
    var x = xO + sqr * (0.5 + (Math.floor(pieceNum / 8) % 2 == 0 ? horz[pieceNum % 8] : pieceNum % 8)),
     y = yO + sqr * (0.9 + 7 * (1 - Math.floor(pieceNum / 16)) - Math.floor((pieceNum % 16) / 8) * (1 - 2 * Math.floor(pieceNum / 16)));
    svg.innerHTML += '<text x="' + x + '" y="' + y + '" text-anchor="middle">&#98' + code + '</text>';
    pieceNum++;
   }
 // Make downloadable
  var serializer = new XMLSerializer(),
   source = serializer.serializeToString(svg);
  if (!source.match(/^<svg[^>]+xmlns="http\:\/\/www\.w3\.org\/2000\/svg"/))
   source = source.replace(/^<svg/, '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"');
  if (!source.match(/^<svg[^>]+"http\:\/\/www\.w3\.org\/1999\/xlink"/))
   source = source.replace(/^<svg/, '<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"');
  source = '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>' + source;
  document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href = "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(source);
});
  </script>
 </head><body>
  <svg width="550" height="550">
  </svg><br />
  <a>Download as a file</a>
</body></html>
```

As you can see, I actually do have an interest in building multi-coloured fonts. I want my chess pieces to retain their semantic meaning to the computer, and so I 'write' them with the Unicode characters from 9812 onwards. And if your display's font is like mine, you'll see monochromatic pieces with gaps in them; it's a crude attempt to simulate a second colour; red squares interfere with the look of the pieces, and a chess position would be unreadable.

On own my display, 'white' pieces on red squares actually don't have a speck of white anywhere inside them; therefore I do not think I am nitpicking, here... I think it's fair to ask that the white king should be white.

**Solution 2: Using a font**

Still use an SVG to define the font, but there will be a lot more manual reading involved.

Don't SVG fonts allow multiple colours in a single glyph? I'm not sure of the exact inheritance rules, and that seems relevant for you. Read and experiment?

[w3c glyph spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/fonts.html#GlyphElement)

If I've understood what I'm reading, changing length-typed values from css can be confusing, because on a glyph defined the way you need, it would actually use the glyph's local coordinate system(?) But colours should be safe.

I may have some code samples later, whenever I get onto this myself. I think it may involve altering the SVG from Javascript; I can't imagine CSS being able to control all the colours of such a customised font. It seems likely to me that 'inherit' is the property to use for a default colour, while other colours used in the glyph would need JS? More here later perhaps, when I know.